# Eclipse CDT で64bitデバッグが実行できない

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

EclipseでCDTを使用しC言語のプログラムを実行しても，
プログラムが始まりません．
停止処理(Terminate)はできますが，ステップ実行(Step Into, Step Over)
はできず，Disassemblyに何も表示されません．
gccオプションに -m32を指定し，32bitでコンパイルすると上手くいきます．
また，gccオプションで-m64を指定し，Eclipseで64bitでコンパイルしたあと，
Eclipseでなくターミナルでgdbを実行した場合は上手くいきます．

OSはCentOS, EclipseはLuna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)を
使用しています

解決方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃれば
教えていただきたいです．
よろしくお願いします．

**(追記**
Eclipse はfile eclipse コマンドの結果がELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64であること，
GDBはコンソールに最初のメッセージで
"This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu"
と表示されること，
OSはuname -aコマンドでx86_64と表示されることから64bitであることを確認しました．
CDTについてはEclipseのHelp->Install New Softwareで入れたので
問題はないかと思いますが，64bitかどうかの調べ方がわかりませんでした

また，デバッグでなく普通に実行する場合は上手くいきます．

また，gdb traceコンソールに

```
break-insert -f *0x0000000008048c14
done,bkpt{number="1",type="breakpoint",
          disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x0000000008048c14"
          ,thread-groups=["i1"],times="0",
          original-location="*0x0000000008048c14"}
(省略)
error,msg="Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Error accessing memory address 0x8048c14: Input/output error."
```

のようなエラーが出ています．
他のコンソールにエラーは出ていません．

Comment: EclipseもしくはCDTを32bitで入れていませんか？環境は64bitですよね？